# How to Query Cosmos DB using Document DB client

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb, document-database

For some reason, I can only use Document DB Client to query my Cosmos Database, so should I use `ReadDatabaseAsync` or `ReadDocumentAsync`?

Or something? For the URI ID, where could I find it?

Comment: Have you not checked out the tutorials that Microsoft have on their documentation website?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-query-sql-api.  And if you have having issues with the `DocumentDbClient`, please update your question with the code that you're currently using

Comment: I've checked, due to some compliance issue, we can not use CosmosDB client

Comment: I am confused.  Can you provide links to the classes that you are only allowed to use?

Comment: You actually use the `CreatDocumentQuery` method to create a query and then enumerate it as shown here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/blob/d17c0ca5be739a359d105cf4112443f65ca2cb72/samples/code-samples/Queries/Program.cs#L122-L138